# NTP Client using the Windows API

Tags: winapi, time, ntp

I'm maintaining a legacy system (pre .NET).  Is there any way to fetch the time from an NTP server using the Windows API?  Failing that, I could probably create a COM object with .NET to do it, but I would rather not go to that effort.

Comment: amazing! I just searched google for "ntp windows api" and this post was the third result.

Comment: Google is certain on top of things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source that I found was http://www.dataman.ro/?page_id=39.

However, I'm leaning toward using the time from a server on the local LAN/WAN, via [NetRemoteTOD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370612%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Windows is supposed to keep the date synchronized from an NTP server automatically, as long as its configured properly on their local time server machine.  Then if their Internet access goes down, I'll still be able to fetch the "standard" time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible. Unless you're quite ambitious, it's probably easiest to start from [working source code](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/ExternalTimeRelatedLinks). I'd go for Terje Mathisen's port, but that's probably because I've known Terje via Usenet (comp.lang.asm.x86) for years -- the other ports are probably perfectly good too.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping that there might be a little plug&play DLL with a simple API, but I guess my life isn't going to be that easy. :)