# How to get the date and time from the internet using MFC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to build an application for tryout, and I need to download the date and time from the site *time.windows.com*, so the application will stop working after several days. I thought about getting the local date and time which the user set up in Windows, but I don't think that's very reliable. I thought about using the classes **CSocket** and **CSocketFile** and something like that, but I am not sure. Can you superheroes please tell me how to download this information from *time.microsoft.com*?

Comment: Thats an *NTP* (network time protocol) server so to read it you need an NTP client; [NTP Client using the Windows API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378235/ntp-client-using-the-windows-api)

Comment: You are trying too hard. It takes only an entry in a user's hosts file to circumvent. What about users that want to try your application but aren't connected to the internet? What about corporate networks that won't let users access your time server of choice? Just use the local system time and concentrate on real features.

Comment: I'm confused. How would a local piece of hardware be less reliable than an internet connection?

Comment: I am worried that the user might set the wrong local time in order to fool the software.

Comment: The thing is, w/o internet access your app won't work.  This is a major negative.  Unless you have a security dongle, this line of thinking will lead to a poor user experience.  Do a quick date check, and be done with it.  Once the app is overdue, throw a flag and stick to that.