# How to use NetRemoteTOD function in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, datetime, mfc

Can anyone give an example to get date/time from internet, which I only found info using NetRemoteTOD function so far.

But the point is I do not know how to use it, what is the server name. I just tried the below code in my function but it gives run time error.

Appreciate helps

```
LPTIME_OF_DAY_INFO pBuf = NULL;
NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
LPTSTR pszServerName = NULL;
int CurrentYear ;
int CurrentMonth ;
int CurrentDay ;
int CurrentHour;
int CurrentMin;

pszServerName = (LPTSTR) "time.windows.com";
//
// Call the NetRemoteTOD function.
//
nStatus = NetRemoteTOD((LPCWSTR) pszServerName,(LPBYTE *)&pBuf);
//
// If the function succeeds, display the current date and time.
//
if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
{
    if (pBuf != NULL)
    {

        CurrentYear =  pBuf->tod_year;
        CurrentMonth =pBuf->tod_month;
        CurrentDay = pBuf->tod_day;
        CurrentHour=pBuf->tod_hours;
        CurrentMin=pBuf->tod_mins;

    }
}
//
// Otherwise, display a system error.
else
{
    m_SharesEdit[9].SetWindowText("No time");
}
//
// Free the allocated buffer.
//
if (pBuf != NULL)
    NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);


    if( CTime(CurrentYear,CurrentMonth,CurrentDay,CurrentHour,CurrentMin,0) >= CTime(2013,11,25,9,00,00) )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`NetRemoteTOD` only works with Windows servers, not to read the time using something like NTP or SNTP. It actually uses RPC to get the time, and I can't quite imagine most people running a Windows server allowing unverified users to make RPC calls on their server, so for most practical purposes, this is going to be restricted to your own local server.

To get the date/time from the Internet (which seems to be your real intent) you want to write or use an NTP or SNTP client, not `NetRemoteTOD`. Windows already has an SNTP client in the form of the w32time service. Others were mentioned in answers to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3378235/179910).

Edit in response to comment: Given that you probably don't care about split-second precision, or anything like that, you might want to write code that follows [RFC 868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc868) to retrieve time. It's only precise to the second, and makes no attempt at compensating for things like network delays (as NTP can), but when the precision you care about is (roughly) to the day, it's probably more than adequate.

It's also quite simple to implement: open a UDP<sup>1</sup> socket on port 37 and read a 4-byte time stamp. That will be given in roughly the traditional Unix format: number of seconds since midnight January 1, 1900. Much simpler than NTP (or SNTP) and probably still entirely adequate to the task at hand.

---

<sub>1. TCP port 37 will work as well, but UDP is usually preferable--you're not doing anything to justify the overhead of TCP.</sub>

Comment: thanks, it seems much complicated than I thought. I am trying program to be disabled after specific date, therefore I don't want to use system time in case user would change it. I think I have to find another way.

Comment: can you elaborate how can i use that info for my date issue ?

Comment: @user2937812: One day is 24*60*60=86400 seconds. So you'd probably want to retrieve time during installation, and store it in (for example) the registry. Each time the program starts, get the current time and check whether it's greater than install_time + N * 86400 (where N in the number of days authorized).

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do. Actually I wanted to get current time properly and compare it with a deadline coded in the program, so I would overcome any issues come with changing system time and in case of formatting OS.Thanks for explanation